# How to find Heap memory of a running process?

Tags: process, memory

I would like to know how to find the heap memory of a process that is running in the background. Is there any command that allows such?

Comment: Check `/proc/$PID/maps`, wher `$PID` is the pid of the process you want to examine.

Comment: Do you need to get the *size* of heap, or its contents?

Answer (score 12):

If you want to look at a particular process named e.g. `wing_ide`, then

```
ps a | fgrep wing_ide | fgrep -v fgrep
```

gives you a number at the beginning of the line (in my case 29837) use this number as follows:

```
fgrep '[heap]' /proc/29837/maps
```

The output look like:

```
01d56000-07026000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                       [heap]
```

If you do this on a regular basis you might want to use the following python program:

```
import sys
import psutil

for p in psutil.process_iter():
    if p.name == sys.argv[1]:
        print(pid)
        for map in p.get_memory_maps(grouped=False):
            if '[heap]' in map.path:
                print(map.addr)
```

To which program you provide the name of the process you want to search as an argument:

```
python findheap.py wing_ide
```

Comment: Anton, How you made wing_ide in process list. I use as well and it shows as python, confusing with my own programs.

Comment: @Gerard patched the startup script. If you make that into a question I will provide you with details.

Comment: @Gerard I did put a question and answer [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/73787/33055)

Comment: how to understand the output?

Comment: @ChopLabalagun use `man proc` and search for `maps` that section has a detailed explanation, Preferably though you shouldn't abuse comments for questions like this, but post your question as a Question on this site instead.

Comment: oh ok, thanks for the info.