# How can you change the process name of Wing IDE from python to something more descriptive

Tags: process, python, system-calls

In my process list under Ubuntu (using `top`/`System Monitor`) one of the largest memory hogs (200+Mb) was `python`. I searched a bit for one of my programs to be the cause until I realised this was my Python IDE ([Wing](http://wingware.com/)), which itself is written in Python.

I thought I could change the name of the program by inserting setproctitle from the [setproctitle](http://code.google.com/p/py-setproctitle/) package, but the python version that Wing is using is different from my own. `setproctitle` needs to be compiled and the python that wing uses is not a full installation (I asked Wing Support but they are unlikely to change that/incorporate setproctitle).

`setproctitle` can only change the name of the running process, so I could not make a script that starts Wing and then change the process name either.

After that I tried to write to /proc/PIDNUM/comm, but although that 'file' is 'rw', I am not allowed to write there.

I finally found a, not-so-portable, solution for this particular case. But I would like to know if there is a standard way of changing the process name of another (possible a child-) process with a Linux system call.

Comment: "setproctitle can only change the name of the running process, so I could not make a script that starts Wing and then change the process name either." It would seem like you could do that, what's to stop you from writing a script that backgrounds the IDE and uses that command to change the proctitle on whatever PID is in `$!`?

Comment: setproctitle is a C extension module for python that I would need to compile with a python that matches the one used by wing. The python for wing does not come as a full installation and does not allow running `python setup.py install`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A process can only write to its own `/proc/pid/comm`. So since it sounds like you can modify the IDE's code, you can just have it write to `/proc/self/comm`.

Another option would be to change the name of its Python executable, and then change all the `#!` lines, but that may be a PITA.

Other—more painful—options would be writing some C code and using `LD_PRELOAD` or `ptrace`.

Comment: That explains why I couldn't test with `echo 'abcd' > /proc/PID/comm`. The second option is the not so portable solution that I found and refered to. Since there is only one shellscript that loads the python executable that was actually very doable.

Comment: I don't think there is a POSIX way of renaming a *different* process. Renaming yourself is fairly portable with `prctl(PR_SET_NAME, …)`

Answer (score 3):

As derobert already indicated, probably the easiest way to get a different name in the process table is by renaming the 'private' python executable from `python` to `wing_ide`.

The startup command, `/usr/bin/wing4.1`, is actually a minimal shell script calling a second script `/usr/lib/wingide4.1/run-wing.sh` this I patched as follows:

```
@@ -66,7 +66,9 @@

 # Location of Python interpreter to use, if not already set
 if [ "${WINGPYTHON}" = "" ]; then
-  if [ -x "${WINGHOME}/bin/PyCore/python" ]; then
+  if [ -x "${WINGHOME}/bin/PyCore/wing_ide" ]; then
+      WINGPYTHON="${WINGHOME}/bin/PyCore/wing_ide"
+  elif [ -x "${WINGHOME}/bin/PyCore/python" ]; then
       WINGPYTHON="${WINGHOME}/bin/PyCore/python"
   elif [ "${WINGIDE_USE_QT4}" = "1" ]; then
       WINGPYTHON="${WINGHOME}/bin/runtime-python2.7/bin/python2.7"
```

in addition to that I copied the `${WINGHOME}/bin/PyCore/python` to `${WINGHOME}/bin/PyCore/wing_ide`.

For Wing 5.0 a similar thing can be done but the default python taken
after installation is

```
  WINGPYTHON="${WINGHOME}/bin/runtime-python2.7/bin/python2.7"
```

so this has to be copied to `wing_ide` in the same directory and used

Answer (score 2):

You can see the entire command used to invoke a process using `top`, but it doesn't show it by default.  Toggle that with lower case `c`.  This should enable you to distinguish one python app from another.

The difference between the command line invocation and the process name shows up in proc too, as `cmdline` and `comm`.